# Replace negative values with null in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I have a calculated column subtracting two dates, but sometimes it will cause a negative number. I still want to keep those rows, but I want it to replace any instance of a negative with a null value. I use the query to make a measure in a pivot and the negatives are creating errors in the pivot.

The column currently is [date1]-[date2].

I have tried all formulas I know, but they don’t work in DAX.

Comment: `if [date1]>[date2] then [date1]-[date2] else null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom columns for this.

Custom1

if [date1]>[date2] then [date1]-[date2] else null

Custom2

if [custom1] <0 then null else [custom1]

Delete the original column & Custom1

Rename Custom2 to Original column name